# Why does I have to solve conflicts multiple time with EGit

Tags: eclipse, git

At my job, we recently switched from SVN to Git. We use EGit for the integration with eclipse

Now, I have to ask the question : When we pull a lot of changeset from origin/master, there often are conflict, especially when we move classes from package to package. Fine we think, we'll just merge them then commit, then push the merge. But no, when we do that, EGit still show incoming changeset from the server, and when we pull them, it create some conflicts, *again*, usually the **same annoying import we just merged**. We have to do it 2 to 4 time before *finally* it is merged

**Why doesn't it just conflict everything once, then be done with it?**

Right now I don't get at all why it operate like this. And of course 3 out of 4 time it happen on my boss computer, and that is *bad* (TM)

And what is the *correct* workflow when we want to fetch some changeset and merge them? In eclipse please, some dev don't feel very easy with the command line.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a few month later, I can say that this was actually a bug in EGit that is now fixed. Sometime when doing a pull, the operation would fail (as opposed to be in conflict). That would lead to a corrupted state in Eclipse, and of course trying to merge in that state would not work.

If you ever suffer from that problem, just update your software. Note that it still affect old versions of Eclipse so if your still on something like Helios (like my boss was) you should probably upgrade the whole IDE.

Moral of the story : keep your software up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

did you commit resolution of conflicts ?

```
git add f1 f2

git commit f1 f2
```

Comment: Right.  You have to `git add` the conflicted files once the conflicts are resolved so git knows they are resolved.

Comment: Well, its fully in eclipse, so we right click the conflicted file, team, add to index, until there is no more little red icon in package explorer, then we right-click, team, commit.